# How can I make a list with most used commands in terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, history

How can I make a list with most used commands in terminal?

I know that this question may be unuseful for any future proposals for some of us, but even like this, the list can be useful when we don't remember a command used once or some times in the past, when we can search at the end of this list.

Comment: Which terminal?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We will use the records from `.bash_history` file to do this. The next command will give you a list of all commands in order that you used them most often:

```
history | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ \t]+|\\|"} {print $3}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

If you want only top 10, you must to add `head` at the command above:

```
history | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ \t]+|\\|"} {print $3}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

To get a specific top, for example top 5, use `head` with `-n 5` option:

[image: Top 5 commands]

If you want the list in reverse order (top with the rarely used commands), don't use `r` oprion for second `sort`:

```
history | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ \t]+|\\|"} {print $3}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

And finally to get a list with the commands used once for example, use `grep ' 1 '` (change `1` with the desired number):

```
history | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ \t]+|\\|"} {print $3}' | sort | uniq -c | grep ' 1 '
```

To deal with `sudo` commands (like `sudo vim foo`), instead of just `{print $3}` in the awk command, use:

```
{if($3 ~ /sudo/) print $4; else print $3}
```

So the entire command would look like:

```
history | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ \t]+|\\|"} {if($3 ~ /sudo/) print $4; else print $3}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

For example:

```
$ history | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ \t]+|\\|"} {print $3}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
    284 vim
    260 git
    187 find
    174 man
    168 echo
    149 rm
    134 awk
    115 pac
    110 sudo
    102 l

$ history | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ \t]+|\\|"} {if($3 ~ /sudo/) print $4; else print $3}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
    298 vim
    260 git
    189 find
    174 man
    168 echo
    153 rm
    134 awk
    115 pac
    102 l
     95 cd
```

You can see the jump in counts for `vim`, `rm`, etc.

Comment: May want to credit your source in your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/68390/1210983

Comment: @ohaal Believe or not, I didn't know about above source; sincerely this was a laboratory problem of a friend what studying at [Computer Science of Iasi](http://www.infoiasi.ro/bin/Main/?language=en).

Comment: @muru The edit you made for sudo does not work for something like `sudo -i` because it gives me `-i` as the command

Comment: @geek1011 `sudo -i` starts a new shell. That history is no longer in your shell's history, but in `root`'s. Obviously these commands don't work for a lot of edge cases; there's no way to deal with *all* possible commands without writing your own parser for shell language.

Comment: @muru I know that already, but is there a way to make it show sudo instead of the argument if the argument starts with a dash?

Comment: @geek1011 sure, add another  check, something like: `if ($3 ~ /sudo/ && $4 !~ /^-/)`

Comment: @muru It worked. Thanks. The command I ended up with is `history | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ \t]+|\\|"} {if($3 ~ /sudo/ && $4 !~ /^-/) print $4; else print $3}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`

Answer (score 3):

Below command will also list the `top 10` most frequently used terminal commands,

```
history | awk '{a[$2]++}END{for(i in a){print a[i] " " i}}' | sort -rn | head
```

Command to list all the commands which are most oftenly used in terminal,

```
history | awk '{a[$2]++}END{for(i in a){print a[i] " " i}}' | sort -rn
```

Answer (score 2):

Fish & Bash - The question doesn't specify a specific shell, just 'terminal'.
Change head to whatever number you want.

**Fish**

`history | awk '{print $1}' | sort  | uniq --count | sort --numeric-sort --reverse | head -10`

```
517 git
314 drush
197 sudo
171 cd
115 man
103 echo
 95 vi
 81 dig
 67 set
 66 ls
```

This Bash one seems to work and is a bit shorter and easier to understand than the other answers. I like the long options to help readability in these types of examples.

**Bash**

`history | awk '{print $2}' | sort  | uniq --count | sort --numeric-sort --reverse | head -10`

```
73 drush
72 exit
65 sudo
46 g
40 echo
35 ll
34 tmux
30 history
30 fish
27 mux
```