# Get history of top 10 commands used

Tags: bash, history

Is there any way to find out top 10 most used commands in history? Here top 10 means commands which I have used most of the time i.e. the commands whose used count is more than others.

Comment: Define "top 10 most used commands". Just the commands or also considering the parameters? Note that `history | sort` can provide much of this, so you should narrow this down a little bit.

Comment: Found required answer in [How can I make a list with most used commands in terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/312428/how-can-i-make-a-list-with-most-used-commands-in-terminal). But the answers given my question are more flexible and easy in terms of usability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a little script myself to check what are the top N commands I have been using lately:

```
mylast () {
        re='^[0-9]+$'
        if ! [[ $1 =~ $re ]] ; then
           echo "error: $1 not a number" >&2
        else
           history | awk '{a[$2]++} END {for (i in a) print a[i], i}' | sort -rn | head -n $1
        fi
}
```

So by saying `mylast 10` it shows the top 10.

This is done by going through the history and storing the 2nd field into in `awk`, so that the count can be tracked through an array.

Sample output:

```
$ mylast 5
248 git
107 python
93 grep
71 awk
52 less
```

Answer (score 4):

One line:

```
history | awk '{CMD[$2]++;count++;}END { for (a in CMD)print CMD[a] " " CMD[a]/count*100 "% " a;}' | grep -v "./" | column -c3 -s " " -t | sort -nr | nl |  head -n10
```

Example output:

```
1  211  21.1%  ls
2  189  18.9%  sudo
3  58   5.8%   man
4  52   5.2%   cd
5  43   4.3%   ping
6  40   4%     apropos
7  34   3.4%   less
8  22   2.2%   cat
9  18   1.8%   which
10  18   1.8%   aspell
```

[This](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/332/what-is-your-10-common-linux-commands/) site provides a little more information.

Comment: Hey, I wanted to apologize for my needlessly aggressive comment on your answer here. Upon reflection, I realized that the question was not very clear and it could indeed have been that the OP was attempting to do it as a different user. I still don't think they would have gotten those errors, but there was no reason to come down so hard on you. My apologies.