# History and aliases issue

Tags: command-line, scripts

I need help regarding shell script. How can I list all commands from history for which is already defined aliases?

Comment: And why would you want to do that? A line in history can contain multiple commands, and so can an alias.

Comment: because I would like to know how many times user type full command but not alias instead.

Comment: Maybe use something like http://askubuntu.com/questions/312428/how-can-i-make-a-list-with-most-used-commands-in-terminal

Comment: I still cannot imagine how to compare these two lists

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sort.1 and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/comm.1

Comment: Right now I tried to export and sort history and alias list of commands, thanks to your links but there is one problem, list with alias consist for example of this line: `alias la='ls -A'` but list of history commands have that line like this `ls -A` so comm cannot conclude that these lines are the same and interesting for me

Answer (score 1):

This may not be perfect but it kind of works:

```
for i in $(alias | sed 's/alias //g;s/=.*$//g'); do history | grep $i; done
```

This should list all the commands listed in history that are listed as an alias for something else. If you have colors set up for grep, this should show the alias in red so you should be able to see if a command is listed but is not the full alias.

For the other way around, to list all commands from history that aliases are set to execute, you can run this instead:

```
for i in $(alias | sed 's/^.*=//g'); do history | egrep "$i"; done
```

Comment: It's the other way around: if `ls -A` is in history and there's an alias for `ls -A`, then OP wants to see `ls -A`

Comment: @muru Okay I was messing around with that first so I will post another.